# Import editable Photoshop text layers into Premiere pro cc 2015?

Tags: premiere

In After Effect when you import a Photoshop file you can import individual layers, and if there are text layers in your file, you can edit them into after effects by converting into editable text.

In Premiere Pro you can import these individual layers but I can't find a way to edit text layers/change there text formatting in premiere pro. You can do that in Photoshop a change will reflect in premiere pro, but is it possible to do inside premiere pro.

Suppose I imported a file with a background layer, one text layer with "Anshuman Chandel" in that layer. Now I want to change "Anshuman Chandel" with "foo bar". I can do that by "edit into Photoshop" option, but can this be done in premiere pro itself as in After Effect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bring them in directly, the way you describe.

After Effects allows you to import your PSD files from Photoshop, making use of editable layers and text.

Premiere does not.

However, you can get this to work by using Adobe Bridge, which comes with the CS suite. Bridge has a utility called Dynamic Link, which allows you to work in realtime in both PS and PPro. You then import in your PSDs with Dynamic Link / Abobe Bridge, and any updates made to the PSD title cards in Photoshop appear immediately.

This allows more than one person to work on a project, one on Chyron and one on cutting.

The only downside is you have to flip back and forth between the two- or use a multi-monitor setup, with PS on one and PPro on the other.

Only other option is to do you edits in AE, where you can bring in the PSDs as actual PSDs with Text, not just the layers.